# How to build next.js app with custom server for production in Typescript

Tags: typescript, next.js

I have a custom express server I use to create an api and to host the static content generated by next.js. When I try to build for production, it says:

`Error: Could not find a production build in the 'path/to/project/.next' directory. Try building your app with 'next build' before starting the production server.`

Answer (score 9):

The next.js project and the custom server must be built separately.

1. Delete any `.next` and `dist` folders
2. In the project root, create an additional tsconfig file called
   `tsconfig.server.json` which extends the main `tsconfig.json`
   configuration. Assuming the custom server is in a folder `./server` and the developer wants the output directory to be called `./dist`.

```
{
  "extends": "./tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs",
    "outDir": "dist",
    "target": "es2017",
    "isolatedModules": false,
    "noEmit": false
  },
  "include": ["server"]
}
```

3. Edit scripts in `package.json`

```
"scripts": {
    "build:server": "tsc --project tsconfig.server.json",
    "build:next": "next build",
    "build": "npm run build:next && npm run build:server",
    "start:prod": "NODE_ENV=production node dist/server/index.js",
    ...
}
```